# At task rest Api - is there a way to retrieve all the task whose project custom field is not nul

Tags: attask

Here is my API example: `attask/api/task/search?project:DE:custom+key_Mod=notnull`.

If I search project with custom field it returns me correct response but when I am searching task it's says:

`Invalid search parameter project:DE:custom+key`

Answer (score 0):

When you're referencing Custom Fields on a related object the "DE:" gets re-arranged a bit: Try the following:

```
/attask/api/task/search?DE:project:custom+key_Mod=notnull
```

Moving the "DE:" in front of your reference to the project should get you the results you're looking for.